# Jquery Animations... question about timing

Tags: jquery

When I have some jquery code as follows:

```
$('#trash-talk-bubble').fadeOut().empty().append(trash_talk).fadeIn();
```

What I expect is the bubble to fade out, followed by the contents getting emptied and followed by the new content being added and then the bubble to fade back in.

Instead the bubble fades, and as it fades out the empty and append commands take place.. and then the fade in occurs.

Maybe  I am misunderstanding how this works..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Should be like this

```
$('#trash-talk-bubble').fadeOut('slow', function() {
  $(this).empty().append(trash_talk).fadeIn();
});
```

this is because empty is called before fadeout is finished, now using this method empty append and fadein will be valled after fadeout is finished.

Comment: that makes sense.. so essentially when i chain stuff it doesnt wait for animation to finish.. for some reason i assumed doing fadeOut().append().. the append would wait to happen untill fadeOut occured.  i know fadeOut().fadeIn() works like that.

Comment: no it wont but you can also use jQuery function delay so it will look like this fadeOut().delay(2000).empty().append('your html').fadeIn();

Comment: im pretty sure the delay will only effect the animations from my testing.. the empty and append happen immediately it seems ignoring the delay